# I have copied database folder from wamp/bin/mysql/data

Tags: mysql

I have copied database folder from wamp/bin/mysql/data

As I open the phpMyAdmin, I see the database name, but when I click on them it is empty, as if no table has been created in them.

Where are my tables now? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Copying the MySQL data directory is not a reliable means of backing up or moving your databases. The supported means is to export then import on the new server. There are a number of things that can go wrong, especially if you have InnoDB type tables.

The basic things you can check are file permissions on the new data directory, MySQL-level user permissions (assuming you're not already logged in as an administrative user, try doing so and see if things improve), and looking in the MySQL error log for any hints if there's something obvious, but it's very likely that something didn't transfer well.

I recommend that you go back to the original installation, verify your data, do a complete export (or "dump") to SQL format, then import that file to your new server.